# How to get Windows User Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created asp.net core app with windows authentication. I see the follwoing line in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
```

It refers to Microsoft.AspnetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.User property, which is only seem to be accessible in a Razor template. Using C#, how can I get the same value in a controller code? What namespaces should be referenced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `TestController` Inherits from `Controller`. `User.Identity.Name` is enough. In other case it is located in

```
namespace System.Security.Principal
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Defines the basic functionality of an identity object.
    public interface IIdentity
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the type of authentication used.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The type of authentication used to identify the user.
        string AuthenticationType { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets a value that indicates whether the user has been authenticated.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the user was authenticated; otherwise, false.
        bool IsAuthenticated { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the name of the current user.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The name of the user on whose behalf the code is running.
        string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use either User.Identity.Name or WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name I get the user "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" returned because the code is published to an IIS server and it reads the servers user as opposed to my local machines windows user name.. If I run it locally through Visual Studio then it does work because it is reading the user on my machine. Anyhow any ideas on how I can get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For getting current user you can use this

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: this will not get the logged in user name, but the identity that the application is running under

Comment: @Haitham Shaddad Hmm let me check. Yep you are correct, my bad

Comment: But the question title is `How to get Windows User Name?`. Since there is no way to get that information from the client, I think this answer was fair enough. Anyway, clients could be on Mac or Linux, so obviously this questions lacks or thinking and research before asking for help...

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended to include the username this way as it depends on the current HTTP Context, so if you tried to unit test your controller, it will always fail as there will be no HTTP Context.

You have to abstract it in an interface and inject the implementation.
ex:

```
 public interface ICurrentUserService
    {
        string LogingName { get; }
    }
```

And in your web project, you implement this interface like this

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
  public LoginName
   {
     get
       {
          return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
       }
    }
 }
```

In your controller class, you will inject a parameter of type `ICurrentUserService`, and use any depdnency injection framework to inject `CurrentUserService`, in your test cases, you can then mock it to return a fixed username

Comment: Question is about ASP.NET Core, there HttpContext doesn't have a static property `Current`. Please read the question carefully before replying

Comment: @Tseng The purpose of the answer is to show the way, not the exact line, he can simply replace the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`; with the equivalent line from asp.net core which is already indicated in many responses